# Using Push Notification For Authentication

Tags: swift, authentication, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, multi-factor-authentication

I am currently developing a system which will allow users to perform authentication without password (passwordless authentication) using push notifications. What I want is that I will have a centralized portal for all the users who will register there and then will use my mobile app (iOS and Android) for authentication (push notification will be sent to the users after entering their user name). My question is that is there any open source platform already available which is providing this kind of functionality? The portal will be publishing several RESTFul web services to be consumed by many other third-party applications as well. They will use web services for authentication purposes only.

My second question is how can I secure (hacker proof) my communication with the portal and mobile app?

Comment: Maybe you can use Firebase?

Comment: @OnurTuna thanks for your reply. Well, I don't have the luxury to use these kinds of services, the management has decided to build their own system.

Comment: try parse. You can use it on your server.